# Wilcox.test for before and after treatment measurements

Tags: r

I am very new at R and probably don't have the experience to rule out if this question is closely related to previous posts. If so, please accept my apology.

I have before and after measures (X0variablename and X1variablename, respectively). Variables are columns in my imported .CSV dataset. I have 11 observations for each variable and want to test whether there is a real difference or not (meadian was calculated using describe fct (psych pack)).

Some columns in my dataset is not suited for this test so I manually wrote all of them:

```
changeipss <- wilcox.test(mydata$X0ipss, mydata$X1ipss)
changeipss

changeqol <- wilcox.test(mydata$X0qol, mydata$X1qol)
changeqol

changeiief <- wilcox.test(mydata$X0iief, mydata$X1oiief)
changeiief

changepsa <- wilcox.test(mydata$X0psa, mydata$X1psa)
changepsa

changeqmax <- wilcox.test(mydata$X0qmax, mydata$X1qmax)
changeqmax

changepvr <- wilcox.test(mydata$X0pvr, mydata$X1pvr)
changepvr

changepv <- wilcox.test(mydata$X0pv, mydata$X1pv)
changepv

changeflow <- wilcox.test(mydata$X0ct_perfusion_flow, mydata$X1ct_perfusion_flow)
changeflow

changectpv <- wilcox.test(mydata$X0pvct, mydata$X1pvct)
changectpv
```

Would this be the correct way to do it? For some variables I get this

> Warning message: In wilcox.test.default(mydata$X0ipss, mydata$X1ipss)
>   :   cannot compute exact p-value with ties

Comment: Maybe have a look [here](http://courses.atlas.illinois.edu/spring2016/STAT/STAT200/RProgramming/NonParametricStats.html) (search for "cannot compute exact p-value with ties")?

Answer (score 0):

If you have two identical values in your data, these are called ties. Having ties, the ranks are not unique anymore and hence you can not compute exact p-values.

Also remember that the Wilcoxon test also assumes a non-skewed distribution. that means it applies only to the paired two-sample case ("signed-rank") or the single sample case.

Usually If you're doing a test of symmetry, If there are just a few ties, you should not worry, but re-check how your data looks like. It is a warning, not an error message. (you get an answer the warning is just to show you that you may be using the wrong test for your type of data and the answer may not be what you're looking for)

Also If you want you can check out the `coin` package in R, which has a `wilcox_test` function that can calculate exact p-values in the presence of ties

Answer (score 0):

Consider splitting your data frame into all *X0* and *X1* variables and then run `mapply` (or its wrapper, `Map`). This allows you to keep similar objects in containers (lists, matrices, data frames, etc.) and not individual variables flooding your global environment and requiring tedious individual assignment.

Plus, as you see, some variables do not correctly run through the `wilcox.test`, for this consider wrapping call in a `tryCatch` to output `NA` for those failed instances:

```
# SUBSET ONLY X0 VARIABLES
mydata_X0 <- mydata[grep("X0", names(mydata))]
# ORDER COLUMNS
mydata_X0 <- mydata_X0[order(names(mydata_X0))]

# SUBSET ONLY X0 VARIABLES
mydata_X1 <- mydata[grep("X1", names(mydata))]
# ORDER COLUMNS
mydata_X1 <- mydata_X1[order(names(mydata_X1))]

# TRY/CATCH WRAPPER TO wilcox.test
wilcox_test_proc <- function(x, y) {
  tryCatch(wilcox.test(x, y),
           error = function(e) NA)
}

# SIMPLIFIED VERSION
wilcox_test_matrix <- mapply(wilcox_test_proc, mydata_X0, mydata_X1)

# LIST VERSION
wilcox_test_list <- Map(wilcox_test_proc, mydata_X0, mydata_X1)
```

Data

```
set.seed(962018)
mydata <- setNames(data.frame(replicate(18, runif(50))),
                   c("X0ipss", "X0quo", "X0oiief", "X0psa", "X0qmax", 
                     "X0pvr", "X0pv", "X0ct_perfusion_flow", "X0pvct",
                     "X1ipss", "X1quo", "X1oiief", "X1psa", "X1qmax", 
                     "X1pvr", "X1pv", "X1ct_perfusion_flow", "X1pvct"))
```

Output

```
wilcox_test_matrix

#             X0ct_perfusion_flow                                
# statistic   1198                                               
# parameter   NULL                                               
# p.value     0.7225658                                          
# null.value  0                                                  
# alternative "two.sided"                                        
# method      "Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction"
#             X0ipss                                             
# statistic   1339                                               
# parameter   NULL                                               
# p.value     0.5417935                                          
# null.value  0                                                  
# alternative "two.sided"                                        
# method      "Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction"
#             X0oiief                                            
# statistic   1206                                               
# parameter   NULL                                               
# p.value     0.7642678                                          
# null.value  0                                                  
# alternative "two.sided"                                        
# method      "Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction"
# ...
```